# SQL Server Management Studio 17.9 installation fails on Windows Server2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-server-2016, ssms-2017

I am trying to install SSMS 17.9 on a Windows 2016 server remotely. But after installation, while trying to open the Management Studio, its showing an error:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).
>   `SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe /install /quiet /passive /norestart /Logs log.txt`  -- This is the installation command i used.

Do I need to install Visual Studio as a pre-requisite? Please suggest a solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No. Visual Studio is not pre-requisite. but .Net framework definitely is. so from role and features please add .Net Framework and re-launch the setup. it should work then